# iOS Textfield / select combo to filter through large set of data

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar

I'm fairly new to iOS programming so please excuse anything idiotic that will precede :)

I have a form, where one of the fields can only be a certain predefined value. The list has over 500 options.

I have implemented the use of Search Bar and Display controller in Storyboard and have parsed the data into NSArray for it to be filtered.

Issue I had was the appearance. So what I've done is applied another View (only View that is in storyboard - not sure if this is correct?) and have placed the TableView and Search box into the view). This way I can show / hide the view.

I then created a button (which will look like a field - if that makes sense) where I've applied action to it to show the view.

I can show the view and search / select a cell (which is subsequently updating the button value)

Issue is, after I've selected a option, I can't do this again, i.e. no further click (IBAction) are coming through. Here's my code:

```
- (IBAction)selectionClick:(id)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{

        _searchView.alpha = 1.0f;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [_searchView setHidden:NO];
    }];
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSString *cellText = cell.textLabel.text;
        [_SelectionValue setTitle:cellText forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [self.view endEditing:YES];
        tableView.hidden = YES;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{

            _SearchView.alpha = 0.0f;                

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

            [_SearchView setHidden:YES];
        }];
    }
}
```

If you need any further info please let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

Setting to 0 alpha and hiding the view doesn't remove the view from the view controller. The view is still present but invisible and block any actions to the view behind hit.

Try

```
    [_SearchView removeFromSuperview];
```

Instead of

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{

        _SearchView.alpha = 0.0f;                

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [_SearchView setHidden:YES];
    }];
```

also
variable names normally start lowercased letter. Most examples follow this format.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I've tried that but it's still not allowing further clicks. Am i adding the view correctly? Interestingly I tried removing the tableView.hidden = YES; to see if that gets removed but this still appears? I only put that in as a mini hack to remove the table view...

Comment: I think I can see what you are trying to do. The way I'd approach it is to think of controlling the container view for your table and search objects. You don't need to hide the table and search bar just the container view. Add it to the main view using [self.view addSubview:yourViewsNameHere]; (when you need it on show) and in the did select method, do your stuff then remove the container view using [yourViewsNameHere removeFromSuperView];